# Given a choice, should I plant sunflowers or sun-shrooms?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

In the early levels, a solid economic foundation of sunflowers is the key to an effective garden. In Act 2, it gets dark, and you start acquiring mushrooms. One of them is the sun-shroom, which gives little suns at first and fullsize suns later. I don't want both, because that's one less slot for offensive seeds.

**Which should I pick, given the choice, sunflowers or sun-shrooms? Why?**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should pick sun-shrooms on night levels, and sunflowers on day levels.

The reason you want to use sunflowers during the day is that sun-shrooms sleep during the day, and they won't work unless you wake them up with the Coffee Bean.

The reason you want to use sun-shrooms at night is because they only cost 25 (instead of 50) sun, and yet they produce 15 sun each. This means that for the 50 sun you start with, you're producing 30 sun instead of 25. This extra sun is needed because there's no passive sun being produced due to it being night time.

The only downside to sun-shrooms is that you get less sun production for the same amount of space (even though they're more cost efficient, they're less space efficient) but this is mitigated due to the fact that after 2 minutes they grow up and begin to produce 25 sun, at which point they become just as space efficient as sunflowers.

Comment: The only exception to this would be if you wanted to plant double sunflowers at night

Answer (score 18):

In a daytime level, there's no reason to use Sun-Shrooms.  They're very expensive during day because you have to wake them up with a Coffee Bean before they'll even produce any sun. Also, you can only build Twin Sunflowers on Sunflowers.

In most of the nighttime levels, start with Sun-Shrooms because they're cheap to start, which is important in the sun-starved nighttime. After a while, Sun-Shrooms will grow up and produce the same Sun as Sunfowers.

In the extra-hard Survival Modes, when you have a very long time to build your garden, you may want to pack Sun-Shrooms, Sunflowers, and Twin Sunflowers.  Start with both Sun-Shrooms and Sunflowers, and when your economy is strong enough to support it, upgrade all the Sun-Shrooms to Sunlowers, and then to Twin Sunflowers.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, it's your choice depending on your play style. Obviously you shouldn't use sun-shrooms during day levels. Night levels you can use either. I completed the game without using any sun-shrooms (only the sunflowers). While it does cost less to create sun-shrooms, in the long run you would be making less sun then you would using a sunflower. In the end, my advice would be to skip the sun-shrooms (more room in the inventory that way too) and just stick with the sunflowers throughout the game.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how many rows of sun producing plants you want.
if you are just doing 1 row, plant sun-shrooms. other then that, plant sunflowers. for 1 row, by the time all your sun-shrooms become fully grown, it produced the exact same amount of sun. The reason you want sun-shrooms tho is that it generates more sun prior to being fully grown so in case something goes wrong, you will have more sun then if you chose sunflower. I dont know why people compare 1 sunflower to 2 sun-shrooms as the recharge time takes out most of that factor. After 1 row of sun-shrooms, sunflowers will produce more in the long run. Like everyone else mentioned, if you want twin sunflowers, go for sunflowers.

Answer (score 1):

It is really about your style of playing, however there is no use of using a sun-shroom in the day unless you bother to use coffee beans. In night levels, I always use sunflowers and sun-shrooms. I do this because with your first 50 sun, you buy 1 sunflower, it makes sun, you buy a sun-shroom, then the cycle repeats until you have enough sun plants. Although you can unlock coffee beans, it's better just to use regular sunflowers. That is just my opinion. It also depends on the plants you choose. For example, if you use both sun plants in a night level, you would have less choices for other plants. I like to choose plants based on the zombies, for if there were tough zombies ( like the football one ), you would want faster and stronger sun producing plants. If you get enough sun, however, you could buy a twin sunflower, but I'd use sunflowers and sun-shrooms. But it does depend on your style of playing, so do what you feel is best. That was just how I play.

Answer (score 1):

i think that the sun-shroom is better at night because you cannot get sun from the sky. I call sun from the sky natural sun. You cannot get natural sun, and sun-shrooms are cheaper. Instead of  getting 25 sun from one sun-**flower**, you can get 30 sun from two sun-**shrooms**. In day, though, use a sunflower. Mushrooms sleep at day.

If you need anymore info, see [this website](http://www.plantsvszombies.wikia.com)